# Encoding differences between tr (ubuntu) and tr (mac)

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, character-encoding

```
echo – | tr ’ X
```

On my mac: correctly prints –

On Ubuntu 10.10: prints XX�

Why?

For reference, the first character is 'EN DASH' (U+2013), the second is 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)

EDIT: I now use Perl instead. The magic incantation that I use is:

```
perl -CSD -p -Mutf8 -e 'tr/A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÄËÏÖÜÂÊÎÔÛÇa-zäëïöüáéíóúàèìòùâèìòùñçßœ/ /cs'
```

It means: except for all letters I could think of, replace any character by a space, and squeeze the spaces.

Comment: What is the `LANG` environment variable set to in each case?

Comment: Not set in either case; LC_ALL set to en_US.UTF-8 on both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU coreutils `tr` has issues with multi-byte characters - it considers them a sequence of single byte characters instead.

Taking this into account, what you see on Linux is "expected":

```
$ echo – | od -t x1
0000000 e2 80 93 0a
0000004
$ echo ’ | od -t x1
0000000 e2 80 99 0a
0000004
$ echo – | tr ’ X | od -t x1
0000000 58 58 93 0a
0000004
```

EDIT:

For a set of UTF-8 compatible utilities, you might want to have a look at the [Heirloom Toolchest](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html). It contains a `tr` implementation that apparently has UTF-8 support, although I have not tested it.

Comment: So, can I install the version that comes with my Mac on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Michiel: It is easiest to just use Perl.  Honest.  It has `tr` built into it.

Comment: Heh, I came to the same conclusion myself (after discovering that Ruby's tr is broken). It doesn't recognize things like [:alnum:] though.

Comment: I also discovered Heirloom, but didn't feel like mucking around with makefiles and potentially breaking the original utilities.